# Compilar jar para exe e não precisar depois ter uma JRE

Tags: java

Mais um problema aqui, e preciso de sua ajuda. Baixei um programa que converte arquivos jar para exe. O único problema é que mesmo assim eu preciso da JRE. Existe algum jeito de converter o programa para exe e depois não precisar da JRE (ou a JRE ir dentro do exe)?

Explicando: quero converter de jar para exe e depois não precisar da JRE (ou ela ir imbutida no programa)

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível, já que você teria que instalar o JRE na máquina do cara, talvez vocÊ consiga criar algum script ao executar o .exe "jar" ele inicie o script verificando se existe um JRE instalado ou não, caso não exista você simplesmente instala a que está "empacotada", mas teria um script para cada plataforma, o que te levaria ter um JRE para cada plataforma. E ai amigo a coisa começa complicar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem algumas ferramentas (comerciais) que fazem a conversão de um JAR para executável, como o [Excelsior](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/) ou o [JexePack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html), que podem fazer o que você quer. Outra alternativa é a criação de um programa de instalação que, além de instalar o seu programa, também instale o JRE caso necessário. O [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) é uma dessas ferramentas. Finalmente, como sugeriu @Eduardobrj, você pode também distribuir o JRE (tanto as suas classes como o java.exe) junto com sua aplicação (de acordo com [esse thread em java.com](https://www.java.net/node/655012) (en)).

Answer (score 2):

Uma vez dependente da JVM para sempre dela dependente. Portanto e quanto à questão de não precisar da JRE a resposta simplista é... impossível, pois o código é baseado em funcionalidade e código JAVA que a aplicação utiliza.

Dito isto... são possíveis algumas soluções que podem compactar o(s) JAR(s) dentro de um EXE, mas incluir o JRE dentro não conheço.

No entanto e em resposta... a melhor solução é com o compilador GCJ.

GCJ pode compilar o código-fonte Java para Java bytecode (ficheiros de classe) ou diretamente para código de máquina nativo, e Java bytecode para código de máquina nativo.

Nesse sentido esta será então a solução à pergunta colocada, mas, "tudo tem um mas" esta solução coloca alguns problemas a médio prazo no que respeita a compatibilidade e manutenção durante a vida de aplicação pois passamos a não poder contar com o que o JAVA tem de melhor na minha opinião. A abstracção do sistema operativo e em especial todo o suporte implícito na ferramentas JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

## Executável sem incluir a JRE (gerando código nativo)

Atualmente há alternativas como o [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) que geram código nativo sem a necessidade de incluir o JRE.

Observe que esta estratégia é diferente daquelas citadas anteriormente, dentre as quais também há opções como [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).