# Qual a finalidade do arquivo (.exe) em programas Java?

Tags: java

Após um tempo criando aplicações desktop em Java, tive a curiosidade de pesquisar algumas aplicações profissionais. Vi que o NetBeans e o Minecraft foram feitos em Java. Mas quando fui ver nas pastas desses programas, encontrei o arquivo principal da aplicação com a extensão (.exe), porém até onde sei os executáveis Java possuem extensão (.jar). Alguém sabe me dizer se em Java também é possível criar executáveis com extensão (.exe), ou para isso é necessário outra linguagem(como C)?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesta matéria talvez você tire suas duvidas.
[Java criando Arquivos executaveis - exe](https://novos-cientistas.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-criando-arquivos-executaveis-exe.html)
espero que te ajude, boa tarde.

Comment: Provável duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30289/132

Answer (score 2):

#### Bom João Hudson... de acordo a uma Matéria de uma pessoa chamada...

> Ciência da Computação - JokerHat

#### Programas Executáveis (.exe)

EXE é a designação à um arquivo com um código fonte interno e inacessível que são apenas executados em plataformas Windows, OS/2 ou DOS. Um simples arquivo que pode ter dependências compostas por DLLs (Dinamyc-Link Library).

São vários os tipos de arquivos .exe que a plataforma Bill Gates possui, variantes com a arquitetura do computador sendo 32 bit ou 64 bit.

A plataforma .NET,que visa a ideologia JAVA, pode-se gerar arquivos .exe com o building. Porém somente são executados em uma máquina que possui o sistema Windows instalado

#### Conclusão

Segundo o Dr. Salina, tornar o .jar um .exe, estaremos 'amarrando' plataforma visto que este tipo de arquivo é executado somente no sistema operacional windows, e java possui característica livre sendo multiplataforma., portanto que ele seja executado em qualquer plataforma desde que respeite suas características. Concordo, em partes, pois, se um sistema é livre, cumpre também a ideia de fazer dele o que bem entendermos. Quando criamos o .exe fechamos seu código, esta é a ideia de sistemas proprietários e também 'dedicados'.

aqui está o link de referencia caso queira ler o artigo completo:
https://novos-cientistas.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-criando-arquivos-executaveis-exe.html